# find mean and corr of 10,000 columns in pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have DF with 10K columns and 70Million rows. I want to calculate the mean and corr of 10K columns. I did below code but it wont work due to code size 64K issue (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16845)

Data:

```
region dept week sal val1  val2  val3 ... val10000   
 US    CS   1     1    2    1     1   ...  2 
 US    CS   2     1.5  2    3     1   ...  2
 US    CS   3     1    2    2     2.1      2
 US    ELE  1     1.1  2    2     2.1      2
 US    ELE  2     2.1  2    2     2.1      2
 US    ELE  3     1    2    1     2   .... 2
 UE    CS   1     2    2    1     2   .... 2
```

Code:

```
aggList =  [func.mean(col) for col in df.columns]  #exclude keys
df2= df.groupBy('region', 'dept').agg(*aggList)
```

code 2

```
aggList =  [func.corr('sal', col).alias(col) for col in df.columns]  #exclude keys
df2  = df.groupBy('region', 'dept', 'week').agg(*aggList)
```

this fails. Is there any alternative way to overcome this bug? and any one tried DF with 10K columns?. Is there any suggestion on performance improvement?

Comment: Correlation of 10k columns? It is a pairwise measure, so you expect to get ~10^8 correlation coefficients?

Comment: @Martin Milichovsky Sorry i missed second column in corr function. I am trying to find the corr between column sal and val1 , sal and value2 ... sal and value10000. Let me know if you have nay questions

Comment: @MartinMilichovsky I think Harish just wants to correlate each column to 'sal'. So no combinatorial explosion.

Answer (score 1):

We also ran into the 64KB issue, but in a where clause, which is filed under another bug report. What we used as a workaround, is simply, to do the operations/transformations in several steps.

In your case, this would mean, that you don't do all the aggregatens in one step. Instead loop over the relevant columns in an outer operation:

- Use [`select`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#select(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)) to create a temporary dataframe, which just contains columns you need for the operation.
- Use the `groupBy` and `agg` like you did, except not for a list of aggregations, but just for on (or two, you could combine the `mean` and `corr`.
- After you received references to all temporary dataframes, use [`withColumn`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#withColumn(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) to append the aggregated columns from the temporary dataframes to a result df.

Due to the lazy evaluation of a Spark DAG, this is of course slower as doing it in one operation. But it should evaluate the whole analysis in one run.

Comment: I had same plan.. but question here is i have to find corr between col 1 to remaining all columns. that means i have to do corr 10,000 times. So storing that in 10,000 temp df's is too much overhead i feel. One more thing is my val columns are dynamic.

Comment: The question is, if the DAG for the many aggregations and the temp DFs does look so dramatically different. If you think in the underlying RDDs, it doesn't make so much difference, as the amount of shuffles, etc. would be the same.

Comment: for col in df.columns:
      df2 = df.groupBy('region', 'dept')    .agg(func.mean(func.col(col)).alias(col + '_m'))
       df2 = df2.withColumn(col, func.col(col) - func.col(col + '_m')).drop(col + '_m')

Comment: ref above code .. is this what you are trying to say? This will loop 10k times? Id not can you correct me please?