# Spark and SparklyR error "grows beyond 64 KB"

Tags: apache-spark, sparklyr

I am getting the following error on Spark after calling logistic regression using SparklyR and Spark 2.0.2.

```
ml_logistic_regression(Data, ml_formula)
```

The dataset that I read into Spark is relatively large (2.2GB). Here is the error message:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 
13 in stage 64.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: 
Lost task 13.0 in stage 64.0 (TID 1132, localhost):    
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
java.lang.Exception: 
failed to compile: org.codehaus.janino.JaninoRuntimeException: 
Code of method "(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;)Z" 
of class "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificPredicate" 
grows beyond 64 KB
```

Others have had a similar issue: https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/298 but I cannot find a resolution. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044779/find-mean-and-corr-of-10-000-columns-in-pyspark-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you subset the data and try running the model? You might need to change your configuration settings to deal with the size of the data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sparklyr)
#configure the spark session and connect
config <- spark_config()
config$`sparklyr.shell.driver-memory` <- "XXG" #change depending on the size of the data
config$`sparklyr.shell.executor-memory` <- "XXG"

sc <-  spark_connect(master='yarn-client', spark_home='/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX',config = config)
```

There are other settings in `spark_config()` that you could change as well to deal with performance. This is just an example of a couple.